# Scala: reduce{_+_} returning negative value because value too high

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm calculating the total size of all events in bytes:

```
val totalSize = sparkContext.map{ case (_, record) => getEventFromRecord(record).toByteArray.size}.reduce{_+_}
```

And writing it to a file like this:

```
val outputWriter = new PrintWriter(fs.create(path))
outputWriter.println("Total size: "+ totalSize)
```

But since the size is too large, I'm getting negative values. I need to convert this to Long. I tried the below change but not sure if it's right:

```
val totalSize = sparkContext.map{ case (_, record) => getEventFromRecord(record).toByteArray.size.toLong}.reduce{_+_}.toLong
```

Comment: Looks right to me (except for the last `.toLong`, you don't need that) ... What makes you not sure?

Comment: I agree with @Dima too

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Long` from the beginning or pack into `BigInt`. `BigInt`s are less efficient since there is overhead of storing it into memory.

Regardless of the solution you would choose, you should use proper type at the moment of addition not at the end of computation.